# Python dictionary being returned

Tags: python

I'm trying to create dictionary with the count of each letter appearing in a list of words. The method `count_letters_v2(word_list)`, print the letters but does not return the dictionary. Why? And how do I fix this? Thank you.

```
def count_letters_v2(word_list):
    count = {}
    for word in word_list:
        print word
        for letter in word:
            print letter
            if letter not in count:
                count[letter] = 1
            else:
                count[letter] = count[letter] + 1
    return count


def main():
    count_letters_v2(['a','short','list','of','words'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It does return the dictionary. That's what `return count` does.

Comment: Confirmation: you don't make anything with `count_letters_v2(['a','short','list','of','words'])`. Try to print it!

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this function. assign the result of `count_letters_v2` to another variable and examine it in the shell. you'll see it contains the counts as expected.

Comment: `print` when you call function to see what it returns.

Comment: also you may want to check the `Counter` builtin, https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does return the dictionary. That's what `return count` does. Do you want to print out the dictionary? Then change `main()` to

```
def main():
    print count_letters_v2(['a','short','list','of','words'])
```

---

For the record, there's a `Counter` object (a subclass of `dict` so can do all the same things) in the standard library that will do this all for you.

```
from collections import Counter
def count_letters_v3(word_list):
    return Counter(''.join(word_list))

print count_letters_v3(['a','short','list','of','words'])
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 1,
         'd': 1,
         'f': 1,
         'h': 1,
         'i': 1,
         'l': 1,
         'o': 3,
         'r': 2,
         's': 3,
         't': 2,
         'w': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, you code works but you didn't do anytinhg with the return value of the function.

That said, I can think of some improvements though. First, the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) method 
of `dict` will make the case of a new letter cleaner, setting the default value to `0`:

```
...
count = {}
for word in word_list:
    for letter in word:
        count[letter] = count.get(letter, 0) + 1
...
```

Otherwise, you can use a `Counter` object from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_letters_v2(word_list):
    count = Counter()
    for word in word_list:
       count.update(word)
    return count
```

If you have a very long list of words, you shouldn't use `str.join` since it builds new string. The `chain_from_iterable` method of `itertools` module will chain the letters for free:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def count_letters_v2(word_list):
    return Counter(chain.from_iterable(word_list))
```

Comment: the chain method is (very slightly) slower than join though:  `x = ['a', 'short', 'list', 'of', 'strings'] * 10_000;` `%timeit Counter(''.join(x));
12.4 ms ± 23.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` `%timeit Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x));
14.5 ms ± 44.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: @FHTMitchell I made some tests that confirm your benchmark. Usual time-space tradeoff (small joke: it's faster until you hit the swap...) But I think one shouldn't make a copy in such a case. It's faster in Python, but will be slower in another language. My opinion is that it's a good habit to avoid copies, unless you *have to* make a copy (performance issue, iterate twice sequentially, ...).